# Read excel values to key value pair using open xml

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml

I have an array of excel cell addresses, I just need to read these cell values to a dictionary, ie, I need to use open xml to do this. Any help?

When I'm reading I'm getting only numeric values and some numbers are coming for string type cells. Or any specific way to read multiple cells from excel using openxml?

```
  public static Dictionary<string, string> GetCellValue(string filePath, string sheetName)
        {
            string[] adderssNames = {   "H29", "H30", "H31", "H32", "H33", "H36", "H37", "H38", "H40", "H41", "H42", "H43", "H47", 
                                        "H48", "H49", "H50", "H51", "H52", "H57", "H58", "H61", "H62", "H65", "H66", "H69", "H70",
                                        "I29", "I30", "I31", "I32", "I33", "I36", "I37", "I38", "I40", "I41", "I42", "I43", "I47", 
                                        "I48", "I49", "I50", "I51", "I52", "I57", "I58", "I61", "I62", "I65", "I66", "I69", "I70",
                                        "J29", "J30", "J31", "J32", "J33", "J36", "J37", "J38", "J40", "J41", "J42", "J43", "J47", 
                                        "J48", "J49", "J50", "J51", "J52", "J57", "J58", "J61", "J62", "J65", "J66", "J69", "J70",
                                        "K29", "K30", "K31", "K32", "K33", "K36", "K37", "K38", "K40", "K41", "K42", "K43", "K47", 
                                        "K48", "K49", "K50", "K51", "K52", "K57", "K58", "K61", "K62", "K65", "K66", "K69", "K70",
                                        "L29", "L30", "L31", "L32", "L33", "L36", "L37", "L38", "L40", "L41", "L42", "L43", "L47", 
                                        "L48", "L49", "L50", "L51", "L52", "L57", "L58", "L61", "L62", "L65", "L66", "L69", "L70",
                                    };

            Dictionary<string, string> cellValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string value = null;

            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {                
                WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

                Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
                  Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (theSheet == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid sheet name");
                }

                WorksheetPart wsPart =
                    (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

                for (int i = 0; i < adderssNames.Length; i++)
                {

                    Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
                      Where(c => c.CellReference == adderssNames[i]).FirstOrDefault();


                    if (theCell != null)
                    {
                        value = theCell.CellValue == null ? "" : theCell.CellValue.Text;

                        cellValues.Add(adderssNames[i], value);

                        if (theCell.DataType != null)
                        {
                            switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                            {
                                case CellValues.SharedString:
                                    var stringTable =
                                        wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                                    if (stringTable != null)
                                    {
                                        value =
                                            stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                            .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case CellValues.Boolean:
                                    switch (value)
                                    {
                                        case "0":
                                            cellValues[adderssNames[i]] = "FALSE";
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            cellValues[adderssNames[i]] = "TRUE";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return cellValues;
        }
```

Thanks
Ragesh